# How to set identity for Windows client for NFS without identity server?

Tags: windows, nfs

I am using the Windows 7 NFS client to access a Fedora FC 11 NFS Server.  The identity presented by Windows NFS Client to the NFS server can only be set in AD or if running a special identity server that runs on Windows Server 2003 R2.

Is there any way to set the identity from a standalone Windows client machine?

Comment: This question might be better suited for ServerFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a tough one. Microsoft's NFS Client is designed for integrating Unix with a business network. It's not really for individual client machines. All the documentation suggests a mapping server of some kind is required.

You may have better luck with a third-party nfs client:

- [nfsAxe](http://www.labf.com/nfsaxe/index.html)
- [DiskAccess](http://www.accessnfs.com/nfs/DiskAccess.asp)
- [Omni NFS](http://www.xlink.com/nfs_products/Omni-NFS_Lite2000/Omni-NFS_Lite2000.aspx)

If you're willing to wait, the CITI research group and the University of Michigan are researching an open-source [NFSv4.1 client for Windows](http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/). Ironically it is being funded by a grant from Microsoft.

Comment: Last update 2012... For the NFSv4.1 at least at the provided link

Answer (score 20):

For Windows 7 *Client for NFS* (packaged with Ultimate and Enterprise versions), you can set the `AnonymousGid` and `AnonymousUid` parameters in the registry of the client machine so that it connects as the Unix user you like.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default]
"AnonymousGid"=dword:00000064
"AnonymousUid"=dword:000001f4
```

Comment: FANTASTIC! I was exactly looking for this! Thanks.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me on Windows 10 Pro. Thank you!

Comment: the anonuid and anongid should match with the linux id of the user or the logonid of the user from win client? Could you also show your /etc/exports ? I am looking for something similar to work on win server 2012.

Comment: I had to restart Windows for this to take effect, but after that worked great.

Answer (score 3):

On non-domain joined machines, you can setup Unix UID/GID to Windows Account mappings using the Lightweight Directory Services on Windows.

Step by step guide is available on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd764497(WS.10).aspx.

A scriptable solution to propagate the UNIX passwd/group files into an LDS instance is available at hhtp://support.microsoft.com/kb/973840

Both work very well when you have non-domain joined machines that need to use NFS protocol.

Answer (score 2):

If you read a lot of off-line documentation by Microsoft, you'll know where to find stuff.

Here's an excerpt from the local ("on-line") help for **Services for NFS** Microsoft Management Control ("snap-in").

> Access to Network File System (NFS) file servers requires UNIX-style user and group identities, which are not the same as Windows user and group identities. To enable users to access NFS shared resources, Client for NFS can retrieve UNIX-style identity data from Active Directory (if the schema includes the appropriate attributes), or from a User Name Mapping server. **If Active Directory does not include UNIX-style identity attributes and a User Name Mapping server is not available on your network, then Client for NFS will attempt to access NFS resources anonymously**.

Comment: Notes: `a)` User Name Mapping is discontinued `b)` Non-domain machines are directed to use LDAP, but it is _really_ buggy `c)` you can help yourself by using ADExplorer from **sysinternals** to get around the buggyness of the in-house utils `d)` I have a successfull Win nfs client to FreeBSD server setup and running without hacking the registry, but "don't try this at home". LDAP setup was the most frustrating part. The MMC kept crashing and there were disappearing list items. `e)` However, overall satisfied with LDAP, because it's for standalone machines, and it _is_ lightweight like the name

Comment: if the nfs resources are accessed anonymously, you cannot restrict access to the share to certain users.