# Restrict nfs server access from windows client for domain users

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, windows-registry, nfs

I have an NFS server setup in Linux (Domain joined) and I'm trying to access the NFS share from windows clients.

I have seen https://superuser.com/a/399212/502713 to set the registry entry for the user anonuid and anongid.

But I still am not able to restrict the access of the fileshare to certain users.

On the Linux server I executed `id -u testuser` and added this UID as the registry entries on the windows client.

I also added the same value on the /etc/exports

`/opt/test *(rw,anonuid=852401208,anongid=852401208)`

Registry entries

[image]

I also have POSIX permissions to the folder added. But this also doesn't work from Windows clients. even the user with permissions to the folder gets access denied. I have tried this from Linux server, all users are able to view the contents of the share except for the folder with POSIX permission.